# PHP multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to at first put all the data in a multidimensional array and later in another function extract that data.. Here is my approach to store data in an array:

```
$data1 = array();

foreach ($line1 as $field => $label){
if (count($points) > 0 && isset($points[0]->$field)){
  $i = 0; 
  $total = count($points); 
  $total = $total > 95 ? 95 : $total;
  foreach ($points as $point){
    if ($i >= $total){
      break;
    }

    $data1 []['line1'] = $point -> $field; 
    $i++;
  }


}
}

  foreach ($line2 as $field => $label){
if (count($points) > 0 && isset($points[0]->$field)){
  $i = 0; 
  $total = count($points); 
  $total = $total > 95 ? 95 : $total;
  foreach ($points as $point){
    if ($i >= $total){
      break;
    }

    $data1 []['line2'] = $point -> $field; 
    $i++;
  }


}
}
```

I then pass the $data1 to a function by serialize the data in a url. The $data1 then unserialize in the function and store in a array. Like this:

```
$data1 = unserialize(urldecode(stripslashes($_GET['mydata1'])));
```

In here now I want to extract the array and save the array data in two arrays. This is what I want to achieve:

```
$line1= store only all the data of $data1[]['line1']
$line2= store only all the data of $data1[]['line2']
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Okk .. Here I got it.. posting it if anybody find it useful.

```
$line1 = array_column($data1, 'line1');
$line2 = array_column($data1, 'line2');
```